# ordering objects by comparator

Tags: android, comparator

I need to order a list of objects, first by date and per date by name.. like the example below via comparator:

```
- 19/03/2014 Anna Hatta
- 19/03/2014 Keller Jay
- 20/03/2014 Anna Hatta
- 20/03/2014 Keller Jay
- 20/03/2014 Zoner Charley
```

I know how to order by date and by name separately, for example:

```
public static Comparator<Prospect> DATE_ORDER_PROSPECTS = new Comparator<Prospect>() {
    public int compare(Prospect p1, Prospect p2) {
        int res = p2.getDate().compareTo(p1.getDate());
        return res;
    }
};
```

But how can I combine these 2 and make a nested ordering?

CHEERS!

Comment: just concat them and compare as one string, but make date as yyyy/mm/dd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Comparator<Prospect> DATE_NAME_PROSPECTS = new Comparator<Prospect>() {
    public int compare(Prospect p1, Prospect p2) {
        int res = p1.getDate().compareTo(p2.getDate());
        return res == 0 ? p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName()) : res;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comparator compare(...), compare by the more important criteria first. If you get 0 (equal), return value obtained by the less important criteria.

This way you can have nested sorting order, with multiple levels of the hierarchy if so required.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Comparator<Prospect> DATE_ORDER_PROSPECTS = new Comparator<Prospect>() {
    public int compare(Prospect p1, Prospect p2) {
        int res = p2.getDate().compareTo(p1.getDate());
        if(res == 0) {
            p2.getName().compareTo(p1.getName());
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```